# Question about finding token addresses to insert into a .sol Contract function

Tags: addresses, network, kovan

Ok so I have a .sol Contract that is trying to find arb between 2 dexes

*I'm utilizing the Kovan Test Network -*

this is the function

```
 function estimateDualDexTrade(address _router1, address _router2, address _token1, address _token2, uint256 _amount) external view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 amtBack1 = getAmountOutMin(_router1, _token1, _token2, _amount);
    uint256 amtBack2 = getAmountOutMin(_router2, _token2, _token1, amtBack1);
    return amtBack2;
}
```

And i'm compiling and deploying in remix.ide

So far, i'm confused on which adddresses to use...per say the Router Addresses and the token addresses..

Because i'm getting so many Addresses from etherscan....do I use the addresses from Kovan etherscan? Is it possible for someone to provide an example.. 2 router adddresses and 2 token addresses?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `getAmountsOut()` Uniswap method?

Comment: Oh hey kerry99 not sure haha, i basically copied the code from a tutorial in a medium article haha.   Is there a site that lists all the current router addresses and token addresses for ethereum?....instead of just going to etherscan and trying to figure it out one by one...

Comment: Please send me  medium article link where you copied this code

Comment: https://jamesbachini.com/dex-arbitrage/